Unable to Add WooCommerce Booking Product to Cart via Custom REST API Endpoint
I'm developing a custom REST API endpoint in WordPress to add a WooCommerce Booking product to the cart programmatically. However, I'm encountering issues where the cart is null, and attempts to add a booking product return false.
Configuration details:

WooCommerce Version: 9.3.3
WooCommerce Bookings Version: 1.15.11
WordPress Version: 6.6.2

Code attempt:
function register_person_types_endpoint()
{
    register_rest_route('custom-api/v1', '/products', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'save_bookable_product',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    ));
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_person_types_endpoint');

// save bookable product
function save_bookable_product()
{
    $response = [];
    $product_id = 215;

    try {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $booking_data = [
            'start_date' => strtotime('2024-11-15 00:00:00'),
            'end_date' => strtotime('2024-11-16 23:59:59'),
            'cost' => 540,
            'resource_id' => '',
        ];

        if (! WC()->session) {
            WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
            WC()->session->init();
        }

        if (! WC()->session->has_session()) {
            WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
        }


        if (! WC()->cart) {
            WC()->cart = new WC_Cart();
        }

        if (! WC()->customer) {
            WC()->customer = new WC_Customer(0);
        }

        $booking_item = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product->get_id(), 1, 0, [], ['booking' => $booking_data]);

        if ($booking_item) {
            $response = rest_ensure_response(["message" => "Booking created", 'booking_item' => $booking_item,  "saved_booking_data" => $booking_data]);
        } else {
            $response = rest_ensure_response([
                "status" => "Failed",
                "message" => 'Product with id ' . $product->get_id() . ' does not saved in the cart.',
                'product' => $product->get_price(),
                'booking_item' => $booking_item
            ]);
            $response->set_status(400);
        }
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        $response = rest_ensure_response(["message" => "Error cached", 'error' => $th->getMessage(), "stack_trace" => $th->getTraceAsString()]);
        $response->set_status(500);
    }
    return $response;
}

Steps Taken:

Confirmed the booking product is published and correctly configured.
Ensured the WooCommerce and Bookings plugins are activated.
Initialized the session and cart manually in my custom endpoint.
-Checked that the product_id being passed is valid and corresponds to a booking product.

Additional Information:
The endpoint is being called via Postman and browser.
